# Error 404: post request with Axios and Netifly

Tags: javascript, webpack, axios, http-status-code-404

Maybe you can help me with the following problem.

I'm currently working on a project.

[Github Project](https://github.com/clemoni/applicative-nlp) // [On Netifly](https://fervent-rosalind-abbe0e.netlify.app/)

On the client side, I'm using **Axios** to perform a post request with route `/getContent`. Once on the server, the content is sent to a third party API to perform analysis. The Response is then send back to the client side.

Everything is working well locally but when deploying the project on **Netifly**, I have an **error 404** when the browser is targeting that route `/getContent'

**POST request on the client Side:**

```js
 const getData = async (txt) => {
        const response = await axios.post("/getContent", { txt });
        return response;
        };
```

**On the server side with express**

```js
/**
 * MeaningCloud Object
 * main param + url
 */
const meaningCloudReq = {
  params: {
    key: null,
    lang: "uk",
    txt: null,
    txtf: "plain",
  },
  url: `https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1`,

  getData: async function () {
    const { params } = this;
    const response = await axios.get(this.url, { params });
    return response.data;
  },
};

const callApi = async (req, res) => {
  const { txt } = req.body;
  const key = process.env.API_KEY;

  const params = { ...meaningCloudReq.params, txt, key };
  const requestApi = { ...meaningCloudReq, params };
  try {
    const data = await requestApi.getData();
    res.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    const status = {
      status: "500",
      msg: "Request did not go throught, contact support.",
    };
    res.send({ status });
  }
};

app.post("/getContent", callApi); // the getContent route
```

Yet, I kept receiving the following error:

> XHR POST https://fervent-rosalind-abbe0e.netlify.app/getContent
> [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 1072ms]

Let me know if you have any idea about what's going on.

Comment: I can only suggest the following speculations:
1. I don't see you have created the route `/getContent` on the backend side code. But this is wrong as you claim that this is working in local.
2. The access token for `meaningcloud` API domain only contains localhost, not your deployed domain, and it's rejecting it.

Comment: I updated the snippet so that the app.post('/getContent, ...) is visible.

Comment: I can't find any other explanation as to why this does not work. Is the correct code even pushed and deployed without errors? Sorry for checking the obvious. :P